# React app POST issues with CORS and fetch

Tags: reactjs, post, request, fetch, cross-domain

I have a basic react app communicating with a SQL database and have a demo API running with Flask. I know my API works with manual confirmation on Postman.

I am simply trying to post data to my database via my verified API. However, I run into issues with fetch based on the headers in my post method. Below is my current code:

```
 const request = new Request("http://155.98.25.80:8000/user", 
        {method: 'POST', 
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "http://localhost:3000/", 
        'Accept':'application/json'}, 
        body: user_data, 
        mode:'cors',
       });
        console.log(request)
        fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                } 
                else {
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.debug(response);
                // ...
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

It is a pretty standard POST request that is triggered on a button click. When I make this request, I can see the API returns a 200 code, meaning it went through to the database. However, in my browser (Chrome) console, I receive the following error: TypeError: Failed to fetch.

I am pretty lost here. I know my post request is going through, but it seems that the return is failing with the response. I have read many of the other posts dealing with this issue, and I am not sure what is going wrong with my app. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this frustrating issue a few years ago and my have an answer for you. Your source of pain is probably the [preflight check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests).

## Why this happens

When you make a `POST` request using postman it hits the `POST` endpoint directly(`POST http://155.98.25.80:8000/user`)

But when you make a `POST` request through Chrome it first goes through a [preflight check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests). This means that it first makes an `OPTIONS` call to the same endpoint (`OPTIONS http://155.98.25.80:8000/user`). The `OPTIONS` call must return what is allowed on that endpoint(for CORS security). The `OPTIONS` call must return headers that lets Chrome what kinds of requests it accepts and from whom.

For you, your `OPTIONS http://155.98.25.80:8000/user` should return

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**Note**: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be your specific api URL(maybe `155.98.25.80`), `*` allows everything

Since `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` allows `POST`, `POST` call will now be allowed when Chrome attempts it.

## How to spot it

If you open Chrome Dev Tools and go to the Network tab you will see how before it makes a `POST` call, it makes a `OPTIONS` call

[image]

The `OPTIONS` call returns the `Access-Control` headers
[image]

Then, the `POST` call can be made
[image]

## Note

Chrome does the preflight check on its own, you don't have to add any additional react code to make this happen.

## TL;DR

Create a new endpoint (`OPTIONS http://155.98.25.80:8000/user`) in Flask API that returns

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added this to my API and it works now

Comment: @Alex_Farley nice! Glad I could help!